# WordPress Page Template Remove Sidebar

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Using a child theme version of Ambition. For some reason the sidebar is displaying at the bottom. How do I edit the child theme or page template to make the sidebar not display.

Here is the link to the live example: http://businessblessed.com/specialoffers/sales-pages/

Here is the page template code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: SQ w Img 2step
*/
?>
<?php
/**
 * This file displays page with no sidebar.
 *
 * @package Theme Horse
 * @subpackage Ambition
 * @since Ambition 1.0
 */
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="cs" class="ie7 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="cs" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="cs" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="cs" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <title>GiveAway</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://businessblessed.com/wp-content/themes/virtue-child/squeeze-page-w-prodImage-2step-optin/css/style.css?v=1" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://businessblessed.com/wp-content/themes/virtue-child/squeeze-page-w-prodImage-2step-optin/css/print.css?v=1" media="print" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
    <script>document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace('no-js', 'js');</script>
</head>
<body class="page-subpage">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="row-main">
            <div class="col col-book">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://businessblessed.com/wp-content/themes/virtue-child/squeeze-page-w-prodImage-2step-optin/img/book.png" alt="book" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-content">
                <div class="in">
                    <p class="read-this"><?php single_post_title(); ?></p>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content( ); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>​
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <p class="secure">Your Information is 100% Secure And Will Never Be Shared With Anyone.</p>
                    <p class="legal"><a href="#">Legal Information</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--[if lte IE 8 ]>
        <img src="http://businessblessed.com/wp-content/themes/virtue-child/squeeze-page-w-prodImage-2step-optin/img/bg.jpg" alt="" class="bg-ie" />
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="http://businessblessed.com/wp-content/themes/virtue-child/squeeze-page-w-prodImage-2step-optin/js/jquery.js?v=1"></script>
    <script src="http://businessblessed.com/wp-content/themes/virtue-child/squeeze-page-w-prodImage-2step-optin/js/app.js?v=1"></script>
    <script>
        App.run({})
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also found a "no sidebar" template inside the parent theme, but I am not sure if it can be applied.

```
<?php
/**
* This file displays page with no sidebar.
*
* @package Theme Horse
* @subpackage Ambition
* @since Ambition 1.0
*/
?>
<?php
/**
* ambition_before_loop_content
 *
 * HOOKED_FUNCTION_NAME PRIORITY
 *
 * ambition_loop_before 10
*/
do_action( 'ambition_before_loop_content' );
/**
* ambition_loop_content
 *
 * HOOKED_FUNCTION_NAME PRIORITY
 *
 * ambition_theloop 10
*/
do_action( 'ambition_loop_content' );
/**
* ambition_after_loop_content
 *
 * HOOKED_FUNCTION_NAME PRIORITY
 *
 * ambition_next_previous 5
 * ambition_loop_after 10
*/
do_action( 'ambition_after_loop_content' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug the_content()
`var_dump(the_content());` and check for sidebar data,

Also You are doing wrong, Only the data after the body you have to write in template file.

Comment: "Debug the_content() var_dump(the_content()); and check for sidebar data," I have no idea what that means. I don't speak PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Every WordPress theme provides page template with sidebar as well as no sidebar.

Here you can easily use the page template with no sidebar by copying it in your sidebar for your purpose and this will be the right way.

Normally WordPress uses get_sidebar() function to display sidebar so check and remove it from your template or can work with hooks like:

If added to a child theme's functions.php file, this will remove the footer sidebars registered by the TwentyTen theme.

```
function remove_some_widgets(){
    // Unregister some of the TwentyTen sidebars
    unregister_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area' );
    unregister_sidebar( 'second-footer-widget-area' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'remove_some_widgets', 11 );
```

If this doesn't work then you can simply hide the sidebar using css by taking the body class within so that the sidebar will be hidden for only specific page for example:

```
.sales_page aside {
  display : none;
}
```

But surely this should be the last option.